# Selecting a cut-off score in SPSS

Tags: spss

I have 5 variables for one questionnaire about social support. I want to define the group with low vs. high support. According to the authors low support is defined as a sum score <= 18 AND two items scoring <= 3.
It would be great to get a dummy variable which shows which people are low vs high in support.

How can I do this in the syntax?

Thanks ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your variables are named Var1, Var2 .... Var5, and that they are consecutive in the dataset, this should work:

```
recode Var1 to Var5 (1 2 3=1)(4 thr hi=0) into L1 to L5.
compute LowSupport = sum(Var1 to Var5) <= 18 and sum(L1 to L5)>=2.
execute.
```

New variable `LowSupport` will have value `1` for rows that have the parameters you defined and 0 for other rows.
Note: If your variables are not consecutive you'll have to list all of them instead of using `Var1 to var5`.